# Why to use ForwardIterator when I can achieve the same using a BidirectionalIterator or RandomAccessIterator

Tags: c++, c++11

What are the performance advantages of using ForwardIterator over BidirectionalIterator or RandomAccessIterator?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Who is the "you" in this scenario? Are you designing a container or iterator? Are you writing an algorithm that consumes iterators? And what makes you think that "ForwardIterator" has anything to do with performance (or at least, in the way you mean it)?

Comment: There aren't any -- every Bidi iterator is a forward iterator, and every random-access iterator is bidi. So you can do strictly more with the stronger guarantees. Usually when something is a forward iterator, that's because that's the best it can be.

Comment: you have the question reversed. instead you shuold ask yourself: why would i use a bidirectional iterator, when i need to iterate only in forward direction? ... and the answer is: you dont

Answer (score 2):

A more restricted iterator category doesn't normally give a performance advantage, as you'd normally use the term. Instead, it gives access to data stored in structures that aren't accessible in other ways.

Looking specifically at forward iterator, it can be used (for one example) for accessing data stored in a singly linked list, where a bidirectional iterator would normally require a doubly linked list.

Using a singly linked list could lead to a performance advantage over a doubly linked list--it only requires one pointer per node instead of two. With fewer pointers per node, you can typically expect to store more nodes in the cache, which can improve performance (considerably) by requiring fewer references to main memory.